# Как в os.walk() указать много типов файла при парсинге?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

```
def Directory(path):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:       
                if((file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1])=='txt'):
                    sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                    tmp.append(sek)
```

У меня есть такой код, он пробегает по папкам/файлам/подпапкам и если найдет файл `.txt` формата добавит его в `tmp` список. Как увеличить кол-во форматов? Вот тут указывается: `if((file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1])=='txt')` там где txt, можно как-то в этой строчке сделать(добавить еще один формат)? Или добавить еще проверку на другой формат ниже `if((file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1])=='txt')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать список и проверять на наличие в списке

`file.decode('cp1251').split('.')[-1]) in ['txt','log','avi']`